# How to insert the dictionary to sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table with the following structure:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usdinrtick(timestamp timestamp, close REAL, bid REAL, ask REAL)")
```

The dictionaries:

```
#1
{buy:{price1:xxx,qty1:xxx,price1:...,qty2:..}} 
#2
{sell:{price1:xxx,qty1:xxx,price1:...,qty2:..}}
```

I want to insert the whole dictionary `#1` to ask and `#2` to bid. I am not sure how to proceed with this. I can increase the number of columns and use the keys to insert the data into columns but just wondering how to do this.

All the answers I have seen so far address how to insert the values of the dictionary rather than the dictionary itself.

Comment: If you insert the entire dictionary into a single column, that precludes the ability to query on the individual values in the dictionary, you do realize that?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, I trust that I will still be able to load it in a pandas dataframe later? I just need to get all the data into the table. I might have to create separate columns at a later date but just want to understand if inserting a dict into a column is possible.

Comment: Certainly it's possible. See the current posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach: convert the dictionary to a string (perhaps [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)) then [insert the row](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute).

SQLite will not be fussed that `bid` and `ask` are defined as REAL, since it uses [manifest typing](https://www.sqlite.org/different.html).